# UIbarbutton blue instead of background image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

i'm trying to add a back button using a custom png file for the background, but every time i add the background using the storyboard it just become blue like this:

How can i add a background image on a UIbarbutton?

[image]

the back button look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard behavior in iOS 7 for an image in a button. The image is rendered as a template image, with opaque areas colored the current tint color, and transparent areas, transparent. If you want to see the image, you need to create the image with imageWithRenderingMode: and pass UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do it grammatically.
I have tried doing it in storyboard, and it looks like there is a really strange bug, that causes the developer to decide - either use text or use an image, not both....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];

     [self addButtonsToNavigationBar];

}


- (void)addButtonsToNavigationBar
{
     UIButton *regularButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100.0f, 30.0f)];
     UIImage *historyButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name.png"];
      // can set the background color instead of setting an image. 
     [regularButton setBackgroundImage:historyButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     [regularButton setTitle:@"Some button name" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [regularButton addTarget:self action:@selector(historyButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     UIBarButtonItem *navigationBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:regularButton];
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = navigationBarButtonItem;
}
```

Comment: i've tried your code but nothing is shown. its really strange.